# Writing to JSON produces TypeError: dump() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)

Tags: python, json

I am trying to load in a json file. Update it and write it back. Here is my attempt at it but I am getting an error:

> TypeError: dump() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)

```
with open('employees.json') as data_file:
    employees = json.load(data_file)
    data_file.close

employees['employees'].append({
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Rob Croft",
    "key": "0003837852"})

with open('employees.json', 'w') as data_file:
    json.dump(employees)
    data_file.close
```

Comment: You don't need `data_file.close` (or more correctly, `data_file.close()` -- the main reason for using `with` is so that it automatically closes the file when  you're done processing the file.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You forgot to pass in the file object:

```
json.dump(employees, data_file)
```

Since you are using the file object as a context manager with the `with` statement, you do not need to manually close the file. And using just  `data_file.close` is *entirely* redundant since you are not even *calling* the `file.close()` method.